# How Can I concatenate a parameter string in javascript function on string in appended html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, concatenation

This is my code for html

```
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Then I append an inpunt to #content:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
       var parameter = "<p>Hola</p>";
       $("#content").append('<div><p>click the button</p>'+
                     '<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="getValue();" >'+  
                     '<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="'+getValue2(parameter)+'" >'+                        
                     '</div>');
});

function getValue2(parameter){
    alert(parameter);
}

function getValue(){
    alert("Hola");
}
```

The first input works very well, but the second input dosen´t work after document is ready. What´s the better way to declare a function in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
onclick="getValue2("' + parameter + '")"
```

But something like this would be better:

```
var $div = $('<div><p>click the botton</p></div>');
var $button = $('<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit">')
    .data('parameter', parameter)
    .click(function () {
        getValue2($(this).data('parameter'));
    }).appendTo($div);

$("#content").append($div);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
'<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="getValue2(\'' + parameter + '\');" >'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
   var parameter = "<p>Hola new</p>";
   $("#content").append('<div><p>click the botton</p>'+
                 '<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="getValue();" >'+  
                 '<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="getValue2(\''+parameter+'\');" >'+                        
                 '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably just weren't separating correctly.

Try this example :

```
onclick= "mySup(\''+json.id+'\',\''+json.description+'\');"
```

Answer (score 0):

The second input should be something like that.

```
'<input type="submit" name="submit_answers" value="Submit" onclick="getValue2('+parameter+')" >'
```

Comment: yes! it works only for numeric parameters. To solve the problem also for strings you will need to put the parameter variable between apostrophes "getValue2("'+parameter+'")".